# User specific entries (relations)

Tags: users, relations, entry, frontend, current-user

Does anyone know how I can show a specific entry to a user (frontend)? My user field is called "gebruiker".

```
{# Get current member e.g URL /members/1/ #}
{% set currentMember = craft.users.id(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}

{# Get current members test entries #}
{% set currentMemberTest = craft.entries.section('test').relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentMember,
    field: 'gebruiker',
}) %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('test').find() %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through `currentMemberTest`, you're currently setting up a fresh criteria model in your `for` loop.

Use your nicely set `currentMemberTest` criteria!

```
{% for entry in currentMemberTest %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```